# turn image into background image through php

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have the following code which wraps the last image in my wordpress post in a `#last-img` div.

html

```
<?php
    preg_match_all('/(<img [^>]*>)/', get_the_content(), $images);

    for( $i=0; isset($images[1]) && $i < count($images[1]); $i++ ) {
        if ($i == end(array_keys($images[1]))) {
            echo sprintf('<div id="last-img">%s</div>', $images[1][$i]);
            continue;
        }

        echo $images[1][$i];
    }
?>
```

css

```
#last-img { ... }
```

I want the image to be the background of `#last-img` instead of just being inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have change the pattern u chosed to use,

and instand of walk through on the entire array u can detect the last array in the var in the code below:

```
<?php
    preg_match_all('/src="([^"]*)"/i', get_the_content(), $images);
    echo $images[1][count($images[1])-1];
?>
```

You can use the "img src" as you please.
GL.

Comment: just to confirm, this will save the last image in what string? (not sure if I asked that correctly)

Comment: its the lists of urls from get_the_content() and store them in $images,
the second row is pulling out the last image.